# Regex for allowing the file extension only once

Tags: java, regex

My validation require a regex with following requirement:

1. The file extension should appear only once e.g.

   - `myfile.pdf`(valid)
   - `myfile.pdf.pdf`(invalid)
2. Valid file extensions are `pdf`, `doc`, `docx`:

   - `myfile.pdf`(valid)
   - `myfile.doc`(valid)
   - `myfile.txt`(invalid)

Could you please help me with the regex expression in Java.

Comment: Would something like myFile.txt.pdf match? It has two extensions but only one is valid.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing? We're not a code writing service, please read the [help] for guidance on asking questions.

Comment: Yes, myFile.txt.pdf would match.

Comment: Is `pdf.pdf` valid?  I think first `pdf` is not an extension.

Comment: I've tried `([^\s]+(\.(?i)(pdf|doc|docx))$)` but it only validate 2)

Comment: `*.pdf.pdf` is invalid since it contains `.pdf` twice

Comment: count the .extension . it should be 1

Comment: It's strange that you would need that: in any file, extension is only a part of file name, nothing more. And file extension by convention is the part after last dot in name.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. but the regex you posted some time ago is returning true for `myfile.pdf.pdf` as well.

Comment: @user868888 Yeah I tested it on regex101.com using the pcre flavour and it worked fine. https://regex101.com/r/6AEuW9/1 Apparently in this case the tiny differences between pcre and java mattered :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the requirements separatedly. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String [] fileNames = {"myfile.pdf","myfile.pdf.pdf","myfile.doc","myfile.txt","myfile.txt.doc"};         
    for(String fileName : fileNames){
        boolean valid = hasValidExtension(fileName) && noDuplicates(fileName);
        System.out.println(fileName+"\t" + (valid?"Valid":"Invalid"));
    }
}

public static boolean hasValidExtension(String fileName){
    String ext = fileName.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)")[1];
    if(ext.equals("pdf")||ext.equals("doc")||ext.equals("docx")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean noDuplicates(String fileName){
    String[] splited = fileName.split("\\.");
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (String str : splited) {
        if (set.add(str) == false) {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```